# Displaying an image based on a variable from a PLC (programmable logic controller)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, plc

I am trying to display an image based on variables from a PLC (programmable logic controller). I want to retrieve the variable from the PLC then get the images from my computer because the PLC doesnt have enough memory to store the images.

Here is my HTML code that is put into the PLC:

```
<script src="http://172.16.0.10:8080//PLCdemo.js" type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){ 
document.getElementById("demo").src = cars[:="variable":]; 
} 
</script>
<img height="800" width="1200" id="demo"></img>
```

The :="variable": tag is the variable from the PLC

Here is my external javascript file (PLCdemo.js) on my computer with images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cars = [  
         "transmission.jpg",
         "High-tensile-steel-plates.jpg",
     "image_306.jpg"
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: What PLC are you using that allows you to program with HTML??

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `cars` like this:

```
var cars = {
    "1": "transmission.jpg",
    "2": "High-tensile-steel-plates.jpg",
    "3": "image_306.jpg"
};
```

I take it that `:="variable":` is a pre-processor directive that will get replaced with the value of the PLC variable named `variable`.

Calling `cars[:="variable":]` will then use the value of `variable` as a key for the associative array. When `variable` has the value of `1` then `cars[:="variable":]` will return `transmission.jpg`.